<ReferenceInput /> not showing previously selected item just because optionValue is set to other than "id"
this is my component:
<ReferenceInput
      alwaysOn
      label="Start Code"
      source="start_code"
      reference="products"
      sort={{ field: "products.code", order: "ASC" }}
      perPage={10}
      enableGetChoices={({ code }) => {
        return !!code;
      }}
    >
      <AutocompleteInput
        optionValue="code" // <= because of this attribute
        optionText="code"
        variant="outlined"
        filterToQuery={(searchText) => {
          return { code: searchText };
        }}
      />
</ReferenceInput>

I put that component in an array as a filters of <List /> component.
After select an item from Start Code, I went to other menu and then go back.
because the default behaviour of <List /> is stores the list parameters (sort, pagination, filters) in localStorage so that users can come back to the list and find it in the same state as when they left it, we expect the previous selected item in Start Code component to be automatically selected again whenever user return to  component, but that's not the case.
And I figured it out, it's because I set optionValue attribute to "code" while the default is "id"
if I delete this line optionValue="code" it works
anyone know how solve this? thanks

Are you sure this comes from optionValue? I have replicated your use case in a codesandbox, and it seems to work without issues. https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/summer-https-xm9r4m
